# Duplicate search with secondary check on another column

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'd like to query in MS Access for duplicate values in column I, but then do a secondary check to make sure A and B exists in column II for the duplicate.

In other words, column I would match duplicate values, column II would make sure values are different (within the subset, making 222 drop out of result).

```
+--------+---------+
|    I   |    II   |  
+--------+---------+
|   111  |    A    |  
--------------------
|   111  |    B    |   
--------------------
|   222  |    A    |  
--------------------
|   222  |    A    | 
+------------------+
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `DISTINCT` keyword for this purpose.

```
select distinct colI, colII
from table1;
```

Which will produce the below result

```
+--------+---------+
|    I   |    II   |  
+--------+---------+
|   111  |    A    |  
--------------------
|   111  |    B    |   
--------------------
|   222  |    A    |  
--------------------
```

If you want rows for only `111` then you can do

```
select colI, colII
from 
(
select colI, colII, 
Max(colII) as maxcolII,
Min(colII) as mincolII
from tabl1
group by colI
) tab
where maxcolII <> mincolII
```

Comment: Thank you, but access SQL does not support Count(Distinct col)

Comment: @userinneedfriendindeed, you added SQL Server tag and so the answer was intended for it. check edited answer and try now.

Comment: @Rahul your second query is not working `Column 'tabl1.colII' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar, that's cause the other column is not part of group by but present in select list. Change the group-by to `group by colI, colII`

Comment: @Rahul  as you said `If you want rows for only 111 then you can do` then it returns 0 rows